# Addig gridsearchCV result automatically to new random forest

Tags: python, python-3.x, random-forest, gridsearchcv

I am using RandomForestRegressor for a regression problem, and using gridsearch to find the best hyperparameters.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
param_grid = {
    'bootstrap': [True],
    'max_depth': [2, 3, 5], 
    'max_features': ['sqrt'], 
    #'min_samples_leaf': [2, 3, 4, 5],
    'min_samples_split': [10, 20, 50],
    'n_estimators': [50, 100, 200, 500]
}

rf = RandomForestRegressor()

grid_search = GridSearchCV(estimator = rf, param_grid = param_grid, 
                          cv = 3, n_jobs = -1, verbose = 2, return_train_score=True)
```

I get the best parameter using this line:

```
grid_search.best_params_
```

Is there a way to automatically add this best parameter to a new randomforestregressor, e.g. to check RMSE value? Something like this:

```
best_rf=RandomForestRegressor(grid_search.best_params_)
```

But sadly this doesn't work i get an error: "n_estimators must be an integer, got <class 'dict'>."

Comment: why cant you extract parameters from just like a normal ```dict``` and pass them into your ```regressor```. Like ```best_n_estimator=dict['n_estimators']```.

Comment: Thanks, it works - somewhy i wanted a simpler way
gridsearch_best_rf=
RandomForestRegressor(bootstrap = list(best_params.values())[0], 
                                         max_depth = list(best_params.values())[1], 
                                         max_features = list(best_params.values())[2], 
                                         min_samples_split = list(best_params.values())[3], 
                                         n_estimators = list(best_params.values())[4],
                                         random_state = 42)